# variadic template specialization issue

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I wanted a generic way to process functions and eventually call them so I wrote the code below the problem is that the code is compiling but when I tested it I get errors of kind

> wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 0)
>      auto al= action::apply<5>::value;

so I know that I'm doing something wrong but I couldn't find out what it is.

```
template<typename T, typename enabled=void, typename ...P>
struct action{
    template<P... args>
    struct apply{ };
};

template<typename FN,typename ...P>
struct action<FN, typename std::enable_if< std::is_function<FN>::value >::type ,P...>{
    template<P... args>
    struct apply{ 
         static const  decltype( std::result_of<FN(P...)>::type ) value = FN( std::forward<P>(args)...);
    };
};


int test(int x)
{
    return x;
}

int main()
{
  auto al= action<decltype(test), int>::apply<5>::value;
  std::cout << "result :" << al <<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is your primary template:

```
template<typename T, typename enabled=void, typename ...P>
struct action
```

Whenever you do `action<blah>`, the arguments are interpreted via this primary template.

```
action<decltype(test), int>
```

so here, you pass `decltype(test)` as `T`, and `int` as `enabled`.  And nothing as `...P`.

We then test to see if any of the template specializations apply.

```
template<typename FN,typename ...P>
struct action<FN, typename std::enable_if< std::is_function<FN>::value >::type ,P...>
```

This needs a break down.  The part *after* `action` is what we pattern match against.  The part *before* is just some variables we deduce from it.

So

```
action<decltype(test), int>
struct action<FN, typename std::enable_if< std::is_function<FN>::value >::type ,P...>
```

line them up:

```
       action<decltype(test), int>
struct action<FN            , typename std::enable_if< std::is_function<FN>::value >::type ,P...>
```

and here are how they correspond:

```
FN=decltype(test)
typename std::enable_if< std::is_function<FN>::value >::type=int
P...=
```

Ok, so argument 1 is `decltype(test)`, aka `int(int)`.  We deduce this to be `FN`.  All good.

Next, there are 2 arguments.  So `...P` is clearly empty.

Argument 2 is in a non-deduced context.  We'll calculated it:

```
typename std::enable_if< std::is_function<FN>::value >::type
typename std::enable_if< std::is_function<int(int)>::value >::type
typename std::enable_if< true >::type
void
```

...well, this specialization says it is `void`.  But we passed `int`.  As `void=int` is nonsense, this specialization does not apply.  We have failed to pattern match here.

Thus we go back to the primary specialization:

```
template<typename T, typename enabled=void, typename ...P>
struct action{
  template<P... args>
  struct apply{ };
};
```

ok, so it has a member template `apply` that ... only takes 0 non-type arguments, because `...P` is empty.

Hence your error.

Specializations are not overloads.  They are pattern matching implementation replacements of the primary template.  The primary template arguments are the signature, always.  The specialization can rename and pattern match certain choices.

You probably want to use an alias.  Rename `action` to `action_helper`.  Optionally put it in a `details` namespace.  Then:

```
template<class T, class...P>
using action = action_helper<T,void,P...>;
```

and use `action` in client code.